# Set wireless channel using netlink API

Tags: c, linux, wifi, netlink

I am developing a WiFi tool in Ubuntu Linux 12.04 environment and I need to switch the WiFi interface between different channels.

Currently I found the solution in Wireshark source code ws80211_utils.c in function called ws80211_set_freq but I do not know how to implement it into my source code and which libs to include and how to compile so I could test it.

The problem is that there are too many arguments and flags you have to use. Also, this is the first time I develop a netlink wifi tool.

If there are any good manuals available where to start and how to use netlink calls for WiFi please provide me with the link.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In current Linux versions, [nl80211](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation/nl80211) is the right way to "talk" to the wireless subsystem. Be aware that you cannot arbitrarily set a channel with every driver and every operating mode (master, client, monitor etc.) Some drivers allow a channel change only when the corresponding interface is "down". In modes such as client ("managed"), the channel cannot be set at all because it is defined by the access point.

Also note that not all wireless device drivers use mac80211/cfg80211. For those drivers not using it, you either have to use the old wireless extensions API or (even worse) a driver-specific proprietary API.

Sadly, there seems to be no up-to-date and complete documentation of the nl80211 interface. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Your approach of looking into the source code of other programs seems to be a reasonable way. You could also use the [source code](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/network/iw/) of the [`iw` command line utility](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw). `iw` has an option to set the channel:

```
$ iw --help
Usage:  iw [options] command
Options:
    --debug     enable netlink debugging
    --version   show version (3.2)
Commands:
…
dev <devname> set channel <channel> [HT20|HT40+|HT40-]
…
```

In `iw`'s [phy.c](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw), line 91ff. you can find the code called when `iw wlan0 set channel` is executed. However, this code is definitely not easy to read. It looks like the 
`NL80211_CMD_SET_WIPHY`command in conjunction with the `NL80211_ATTR_WIPHY_FREQ` attribute is the way to go.

In [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21604955/1566044) you can find a skeleton program for using nl80211. Also, the code of Aircrack-ng ([`src/osdep/linux.c`](http://svn.aircrack-ng.org/trunk/src/osdep/linux.c), function `linux_set_channel_nl80211`) could act as a blueprint.

Comment: Thanks! You're right I should set operating mode to monitor mode to be able to change the channel and I used the sample code from wireshark APIs. Installed libnl-dev and compiled with -lnl netlink library flag. But I have this error happens " Device or resource busy (-16) " sometimes and I do not know what is causing it.

Comment: Which wireless driver do you use? You can look up the source code of cfg80211 and/or the driver you are using to see what circumstances could cause an `-EBUSY` condition. If my answer solves your problem please upvote it and/or select it as accepted answer.

Comment: It seems my driver is OK. The solution was: sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor && ifconfig wlan0 down.

Comment: You can find a good [documentation](http://www.carisma.slowglass.com/~tgr/libnl/doc/core.html) at the [projects website](http://www.carisma.slowglass.com/~tgr/libnl/).

Comment: @Phidelux this is the general documentation of libnl and netlink sockets. nl80211 is not described there. This is like a description of UDP does not explain DNS ;-) I'm not aware of a nl80211 documentation, but I really wish there was one.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, but the header file nl80211.h is very well commented.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is currently correct, but there's no example code posted yet which solves the OP's question (even if nearly 4 years late), so I thought I would add this here for any future search engine users. It's adapted from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21604955/1566044) and the specific Aircrack-ng file ([/src/aircrack-osdep/linux.c](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/blob/master/src/aircrack-osdep/linux.c), line 1050) that were both previously mentioned.

```
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netlink/netlink.h>
#include <netlink/genl/genl.h>
#include <netlink/genl/ctrl.h>
#include <linux/nl80211.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* The device's name and the frequency we wish to set it to. */
    char *device = "wlan1";
    int frequencyMhz = 2442;

    /* Create the socket and connect to it. */
    struct nl_sock *sckt = nl_socket_alloc();
    genl_connect(sckt);

    /* Allocate a new message. */
    struct nl_msg *mesg = nlmsg_alloc();

    /* Check /usr/include/linux/nl80211.h for a list of commands and attributes. */
    enum nl80211_commands command = NL80211_CMD_SET_WIPHY;

    /* Create the message so it will send a command to the nl80211 interface. */
    genlmsg_put(mesg, 0, 0, genl_ctrl_resolve(sckt, "nl80211"), 0, 0, command, 0);

    /* Add specific attributes to change the frequency of the device. */
    NLA_PUT_U32(mesg, NL80211_ATTR_IFINDEX, if_nametoindex(device));
    NLA_PUT_U32(mesg, NL80211_ATTR_WIPHY_FREQ, frequencyMhz);

    /* Finally send it and receive the amount of bytes sent. */
    int ret = nl_send_auto_complete(sckt, mesg);
    printf("%d Bytes Sent\n", ret);

    nlmsg_free(mesg);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    nla_put_failure:
        nlmsg_free(mesg);
        printf("PUT Failure\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Compile this with `gcc main.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libnl-3.0 libnl-genl-3.0)`.
Once executed, check the frequency/channel of your device with e.g. `iw wlan1 info` or `iwconfig`. There's no serious error checking here, so all you will notice is if the message was sent or not. Hopefully this helps anyone like me making the transition from Wireless Extensions to cfg80211 and nl80211.

Comment: `nl_send_auto_complete` is deprecated. Use `nl_send_auto`

Comment: `NL80211_CMD_SET_WIPHY` too, use `NL80211_CMD_SET_CHANNEL`