# How can I link libraries to my C code and use that in a Rust binary?

Tags: c, linker, rust, ffi

I am trying to include a C file in my Rust project. The C file uses system dependencies. Below is a minimal example that does not compile when I run `cargo build`.

If I take the failing command that Cargo is running and I append `"-l" "nl-genl-3" "-l" "nl-3"` the command *does* succeed. Is it putting the the linker flags in the wrong place, because those flags definitely *are* in the command?

**src/main.rs**

```
#[link(name = "nl-genl-3")]
#[link(name = "nl-3")]
extern "C" {
    fn nl_test(help_me_pls: usize) -> usize;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        println!("nl.c function result: {:?}", nl_test(6));
    }
}
```

**src/nl.c**

```c
#include <linux/nl80211.h>
#include <netlink/netlink.h>
#include <netlink/genl/genl.h>

int nl_test(int help_me_pls) {
    struct nl_sock* socket = nl_socket_alloc();
    nl_socket_free(socket);
    return help_me_pls;
}
```

**build.rs**

```
extern crate cc;

fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .include("/usr/include/libnl3")
        .file("src/nl.c")
        .compile("libnl.a");
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "derp"
version = "0.1.0"

[build-dependencies]
cc = "1.0"
```

I get the following output when I run `cargo build`

```
   Compiling cc v1.0.18
   Compiling derp v0.1.0 (file:///root/derp)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-L" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib" "/root/derp/target/debug/deps/derp-5a7445c256565e2d.1vmrdj4gsxr690x4.rcgu.o" "/root/derp/target/debug/deps/derp-5a7445c256565e2d.1y16o1qfye96o7m0.rcgu.o" "/root/derp/target/debug/deps/derp-5a7445c256565e2d.3rngp6bm2u2q5z0y.rcgu.o" "/root/derp/target/debug/deps/derp-5a7445c256565e2d.4oc10dk278mpk1vy.rcgu.o" "/root/derp/target/debug/deps/derp-5a7445c256565e2d.4xq48u46a1pwiqn7.rcgu.o" "/root/derp/target/debug/deps/derp-5a7445c256565e2d.51s1w397y42gpez1.rcgu.o" "/root/derp/target/debug/deps/derp-5a7445c256565e2d.8xzrsc1ux72v29j.rcgu.o" "/root/derp/target/debug/deps/derp-5a7445c256565e2d.oa3rad818d8sgn4.rcgu.o" "-o" "/root/derp/target/debug/deps/derp-5a7445c256565e2d" "/root/derp/target/debug/deps/derp-5a7445c256565e2d.crate.allocator.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/root/derp/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/root/derp/target/debug/build/derp-c3cdcf1fbd0c70b2/out" "-L" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib" "-l" "nl-genl-3" "-l" "nl-3" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "-Wl,--whole-archive" "-l" "nl" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--start-group" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstd-774f1a5992f88ec5.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libpanic_unwind-a65ab1ab71045d14.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/liballoc_jemalloc-5cced33d7a39db8e.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libunwind-76fba694360269fc.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/liballoc_system-b3f660c2be971c37.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/liblibc-64d840c62d40ace0.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/liballoc-b3d8b67c899d207d.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libcore-d9124265921c5963.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libcompiler_builtins-1aad7d9a81def783.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-l" "dl" "-l" "rt" "-l" "pthread" "-l" "pthread" "-l" "gcc_s" "-l" "c" "-l" "m" "-l" "rt" "-l" "pthread" "-l" "util" "-l" "util"
  = note: /root/derp/target/debug/build/derp-c3cdcf1fbd0c70b2/out/libnl.a(nl.o): In function `nl_test':
          /root/derp/src/nl.c:6: undefined reference to `nl_socket_alloc'
          /root/derp/src/nl.c:7: undefined reference to `nl_socket_free'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Where did you tell cargo to link your library ?

Comment: FWIW, a `usize` and an `int` are **not** guaranteed to be the same size. You should be using `libc::c_int` in Rust to ensure you match.

Comment: [Possibly relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27959146/1922722)

Comment: Is there a difference between using `libc::c_int` and `std::os::raw::c_int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Cargo documentation for build scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html):

> `rustc-link-lib=[KIND=]NAME` indicates that the specified value is a
>   library name and should be passed to the compiler as a `-l` flag. The
>   optional `KIND` can be one of `static`, `dylib` (the default), or `framework`,
>   see `rustc --help` for more details.

Add this to your build script:

```
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=nl-genl-3");
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=nl-3");
```

And remove the `link` attributes from your Rust code.

---

The problem is that your linker flags are stating that the Rust code needs to link to the C libraries, but that's not fully true. Your *C code* needs to link to the libraries, and your Rust code needs to link to the compiled C code. If you look at the arguments, you'll see this (abridged) output

- `deps/derp-5a7445c256565e2d.1vmrdj4gsxr690x4.rcgu.o` (your Rust code)
- `-l nl-genl-3` (system library)
- `-l nl-3` (system library)
- `-l nl` (your C shim)

Argument order to linkers is important. If something isn't needed when the object is processed by the linker, *it won't be used*.

Here, the Rust code adds a dependency on code from the `nl` library, so the linker is on the lookout for those symbols. When `nl-3` and `nl-genl-3` are processed, we don't need any of the symbols from them, so they are mostly ignored. When `nl` is processed, we resolve the dependency from the Rust code, but `nl` needs the symbols from `nl-genl-3` and `nl-3`, which will not be processed again.

It's not obvious, but the `compile` method from `cc` automatically prints out a `cargo:rustc-link-lib` line to tie its build result into your Rust code.

See also:

- [How do I specify the linker path in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40833078/155423)
- [Linking Rust application with a dynamic library not in the runtime linker search path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40602708/155423)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how I solved it [Rust + .so lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60236701/how-to-use-a-compiled-c-so-file-in-rust/67748307#67748307). Hope It would help