# How to connect my device to wifi with libnl?

Tags: c, linux, wifi, netlink, iwconfig

I'm creating a  C library that manage a lot of pheripherical of my embedded device. The S.O. used, is a linux dristro compiled with yocto. I'm trying to make some functions to connect my device to a wifi (well-know) router, with netlink (using the libnl commands). With the help of this community i've developed a function able to scan the routers in the area [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062268/using-nl80211-h-to-scan-access-points) . Some of you know how to use the libnl command for connect my device to a router wifi?

I've developed the following code, that try to connect to an AP called "Validator_Test" (that have no password for authentication). The software return no error, but my device still remain disconneted from the ap.

```
static int iw_conn() {

    struct nl_msg *msg = nlmsg_alloc();

    int if_index = if_nametoindex("wlan0"); // Use this wireless interface for scanning.

    // Open socket to kernel.
    struct nl_sock *socket = nl_socket_alloc();  // Allocate new netlink socket in memory.
    genl_connect(socket);  // Create file descriptor and bind socket.
    int driver_id = genl_ctrl_resolve(socket, "nl80211");  // Find the nl80211 driver ID.

    genlmsg_put(msg, 0, 0, driver_id, 0, (NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_ACK), NL80211_CMD_CONNECT, 0); 

    nla_put_u32(msg, NL80211_ATTR_IFINDEX, if_index);  // Add message attribute, which interface to use.

    nla_put(msg, NL80211_ATTR_SSID, strlen("Validator_Test"), "Validator_Test"); 

    nla_put(msg, NL80211_ATTR_MAC, strlen("00:1e:42:21:e4:e9"), "00:1e:42:21:e4:e9");  

    int ret = nl_send_auto_complete(socket, msg);  // Send the message.
    printf("NL80211_CMD_CONNECT sent %d bytes to the kernel.\n", ret);
    ret = nl_recvmsgs_default(socket);  // Retrieve the kernel's answer. callback_dump() prints SSIDs to stdout.
    nlmsg_free(msg);

    if (ret < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: nl_recvmsgs_default() returned %d (%s).\n", ret, nl_geterror(-ret));
        return ret;
    }

    nla_put_failure:
    return -ENOSPC;
}
```

Comment: Question is too broad in my opinion, please provide an approach to discuss about.

Answer (score 1):

It seems similar to this one: 
[How to use libnl and netlink socket for connect devices to AP programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793581/how-to-use-libnl-and-netlink-socket-for-connect-devices-to-ap-programatically)

--
Thanks for the code.

Based on your code, I modified and did the test here; it works. The source code is at: https://github.com/neojou/nl80211/blob/master/test_connect/src/test_connect_nl80211.c

Some suggestions for this:

Make sure the test environment is correct

Before test the code, maybe you can try to use iw to do the test. iw is the open source tool, which uses netlink also. you can type "sudo iw wlan0 connect Validator_Test" and then use iwconfig to see if it is connected or not first. ( Suppose there is no security setting at the AP as you said )

there are two differences between your source code and mine

(1) don't need to set NL80211_ATTR_MAC

(2) ret = nl_recvmsgs_default(socket);

not sure if there is any judgement of the return value of your ap_conn(), but it seems better to return 0 in ap_conn(), when nl_recvmsgs_default() returns 0.